# Actuator bandwidth

Tags: rockets, flight-control, mission-control, gimbaled-engines

What is the relationship between the slew rate of the linear actuator and bandwidth? What should be the slew rate if I want 5 Hz actuator bandwidth?

For more details:-
I'm using a 2nd transfer function for this linear actuator in control stability analysis, so there I selected 5 Hz as actuator bandwidth and now I want to fix my linear actuator slew rate for this bandwidth requirement.
Operating Range :- -20 mm to + 20 mm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just imagine a linear sawtooth signal with 5 Hz frequency. You need the amplitude of the actuator to calculate the slew rate.The actuator should move from minimum to maximum and back within a period of the 5 Hz signal.

Comment: **1** By `linear actuator` do you mean an actuator which moves stuff along a line or an actuator whose behavior is specified by linear equations ? **2** What is the maximum range of movement of the actuator ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is off topic. It is better suited for e.g. the Electrical Engineering SE.

Comment: @Ludo I'd recommend Engineering SE, EESE can be absolutely brutal to new users and *electromechanical* questions fit there just fine.